# How can I create the pattern for the first four lags for the remaining groups?

Tags: r, lag

[image: Lag]

My current code

```
GuestFirst_B$Lag_Loyal2 <- Lag(Loyal, shift = 1)
GuestFirst_B$Lag_Loyal1[which(!duplicated(GuestFirst_B$Property))] <- NA

GuestFirst_B$Lag_Loyal2 <- Lag(Loyal, shift = 2)
GuestFirst_B$Lag_Loyal2[which(!duplicated(GuestFirst_B$Property))] <- NA

GuestFirst_B$Lag_Loyal3 <- Lag(Loyal, shift = 3)
GuestFirst_B$Lag_Loyal3[which(!duplicated(GuestFirst_B$Property))] <- NA

GuestFirst_B$Lag_Loyal4 <- Lag(Loyal, shift = 4)
GuestFirst_B$Lag_Loyal4[which(!duplicated(GuestFirst_B$Property))] <- NA
```

I am basically having 1 property (in this case hotel) that is measured over 5 years and I am trying to recreate the first pattern for all groups

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option would be to use `shift` from `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)[, paste0("Lag_Loyal", 1:4) := shift(Loyal, 1:4), by = grp]
```